# Post request sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, httprequest, alamofire

In my iOS app, I am using the Alamofire library.
For all the post requests I am using in my app, I am seeing the same issue: most of the times it works, but sometimes(seems randomly) I am getting an error like this:

[image: error]

I wanted to debug this, so I activated CFNETWORK_DIAGNOSTICS(3) which gave me more info about the issue, but I am not able to see what is going wrong.

## The console message when the httprequest fails:

[image: http request fail message]

## The console message when the httprequest completes succesfully:

[image: http request complete succesfully]

Could anyone help me out please?

Comment: i suggest you to use `moya`

Comment: Dont add a 2nd framework as mentioned above, you've already used alamofire unnecessarily, use a tool like charles proxy, using this can help to identify if its your code or the web service that is the issue.

Comment: Mark the difference in the 'working' and 'not working' examples - takes a lot of time for others to look through what appears to be very similar things - and show where you are getting that 999 'canceled' error you describe at first.  The more help you can be to those trying to help you, the more likely to get help from them.

Comment: Can you provide code of using Alamofire?